# Scanner multiple inputs issue

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a student at a local tech in Ireland first year. We are as you guessed doing java and the at the moment we are handling Scanners at the moment. I have added my code at the bottom and a little confused.

When I run the program it works fine till I get to the "Enter country" and the "Enter course" and these two line land up printing together no matter if I change the scanner to f.nextLine or f.next.

Anyone able to help me out with this as I am missing something and I can't figure out what it is.

Many thanks

Matthew

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String name; //declaring string name
    String town; //declaring string town
    double dist; //declaring double distance from AIT the person lives
    int age; //declaring their age 
    double height; //declaring their height
    double weight; //declaring their weight
    String country; //declaring their country that they are from
    String course; //declaring their course that they are taking 
    int years; //declaring the amount of years they are in the course
    String sNum; //declaring there email address string

    Scanner f = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    // below is the prompt for all the information and there keyboard input with scanner
    System.out.print("Enter your name here & press enter: "); 
    name = f.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the name of the town or city you live in & press enter: ");
    town = f.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the distance from AIT that you live in kilometers & press enter: ");
    dist = f.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter your age & press enter: ");
    age = f.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter your height & press enter: ");
    height = f.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter your weight & press enter: ");
    weight = f.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter the name of country that you are from & press enter: ");
    country = f.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the name of course you are taking & press enter: ");
    course = f.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the number of years the course is & press enter: ");
    years = f.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter your student number & press enter: ");
    sNum = f.next();

    //all the outputs of the information collected
    System.out.println("Your name: "+name+" Town: "+town);
    System.out.println(town+" is "+dist+" away from AIT.");
    System.out.println("You are "+height+" meters tall & "+weight+" kgs & you are a "+country+" citizen.");
    System.out.println("Your studying "+course+" for "+years+" years at AIT.");
    System.out.println("Your student number is "+sNum+" & your student email address is         "+sNum+"@student.ait.ie");
    System.out.println("Please review the information.");
}
```

Comment: please read this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551985/java-nextline-and-nextdouble-differences

you need to add an extra "newLine" before the country read

Comment: If any of the answers solved the problem please accept one (green checkmark), you may also upvote useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nextDouble() scans the next token and parses it into a double. That is why you are facing this issue. You can simply move you nextLine() above the nextDouble(). Its a temporary solution to solve the problem.

Try below code. I just edited your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String name; //declaring string name
    String town; //declaring string town
    double dist; //declaring double distance from AIT the person lives
    int age; //declaring their age 
    double height; //declaring their height
    double weight; //declaring their weight
    String country; //declaring their country that they are from
    String course; //declaring their course that they are taking 
    int years; //declaring the amount of years they are in the course
    String sNum; //declaring there email address string

    Scanner f = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    // below is the prompt for all the information and there keyboard input with scanner
    System.out.print("Enter your name here & press enter: "); 
    name = f.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the name of the town or city you live in & press enter: ");
    town = f.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter the name of country that you are from & press enter: ");
    country = f.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the name of course you are taking & press enter: ");
    course = f.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the number of years the course is & press enter: ");
    years = f.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter your student number & press enter: ");
    sNum = f.next();

    System.out.print("Enter the distance from AIT that you live in kilometers & press enter: ");
    dist = f.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter your age & press enter: ");
    age = f.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter your height & press enter: ");
    height = f.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter your weight & press enter: ");
    weight = f.nextDouble();



    //all the outputs of the information collected
    System.out.println("Your name: "+name+" Town: "+town);
    System.out.println(town+" is "+dist+" away from AIT.");
    System.out.println("You are "+height+" meters tall & "+weight+" kgs & you are a "+country+" citizen.");
    System.out.println("Your studying "+course+" for "+years+" years at AIT.");
    System.out.println("Your student number is "+sNum+" & your student email address is         "+sNum+"@student.ait.ie");
    System.out.println("Please review the information.");

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
    System.out.print("Enter the name of country that you are from & press enter: ");
    country = f.next();
    System.out.print("Enter the name of course you are taking & press enter: ");
    course = f.next();
```

it will work. You can do this for the other `nextLine`s also. For some reason you read the student number as a string instead of a number, but since you treat all you input as strings, you could just use `next` for everything.

**Edit:**

Don't forget to call `f.close()` to close the scanner.