# Why is this program not running correctly?

Tags: java, user-input

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //System.out.println("Enter quantity:");
    //int quantity = input.nextInt();
    //System.out.println("You entered: " + quantity);

    //System.out.println("Enter price: ");
    //double price = input.nextDouble();
    //System.out.println("You entered: " + price);

    System.out.println("Enter city: ");
    String city = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You entered: " + city);
    System.out.println("Enter state code: ");
    String state = input.next();
    System.out.println("You entered: " + state);
}

}
```

When I run the program with the middle section commented out like this, it works correctly. But when I uncomment it, it messes up the last block by printing the following lines simultaneously:

```
Enter city: 
You entered: 
Enter state code:
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You pressed ENTER after you typed the price, correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: .nextLine() and .nextDouble() differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551985/java-nextline-and-nextdouble-differences)

Comment: Yes, I pressed enter. Also, can someone tell me if I should close my questions if they get marked as duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

You typed something like this:

```
12<enter>1.3<enter>AZ
```

right?

When you call `nextInt`, it reads the next integer. So it reads "12" and what is left is:

```
<enter>1.3<enter>AZ<enter>
```

Now you call `nextDouble`. It skips past the first <enter> and reads "1.3" (a double). What is left is:

```
<enter>AZ<enter>
```

Now you call `nextLine`, which reads until the next <enter>. Oh look, you already pressed <enter>! So it reads the <enter> and returns a blank line. What is left is:

```
AZ<enter>
```

Now you call `nextLine` again, which reads until the next <enter>. It reads `AZ<enter>` and returns "AZ".

This is a quirk of how `Scanner`s and streams work. The usual fix is to call `nextLine` immediately after `nextInt` and `nextDouble`, and ignore the result. Something like:

```
System.out.println("Enter quantity: ");
int quantity = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); // ignore newline
System.out.println("You entered: " + quantity);

System.out.println("Enter price: ");
double price = input.nextDouble();
input.nextLine(); // ignore newline
System.out.println("You entered: " + price);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input.nextDouble();
```

does not consume the line, insert a line:`input.nextLine();`
right after the commented block, don't assign it to any variable.

Comment: Thanks, but could you tell me if I should close this question or accept your answer, because the site says its a duplicate? I'm new to this site so I don't know.

Comment: :) anyway you want to do it

Answer (score 0):

**use ScnObj.next() instead of ScnObj.nextLine();**

```
System.out.println("Enter price: ");
double price = ScnObj.nextDouble();
System.out.println("You entered: " + price);

System.out.println("Enter city: ");
String city = ScnObj.next();
System.out.println("You entered: " + city);

System.out.println("Enter state code: ");
String state = ScnObj.next();
System.out.println("You entered: " + state);
```