# InputMismatchException when working with java.util.Scanner in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I'm trying to create a sort of inventory storage program where users can enter, remove, and search for items and prices. However when entering values, I get an InputMismatchException. Here is the WIP code I have so far:

```
String item;
        double price;

        while(running == true){

            System.out.println("Enter the item");

            item = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the price");

            price = input.nextDouble();

            inv.put(item, price);

           System.out.println(inv);

        }
```

What I've noticed is that on the second iteration of the loop, it skips over taking the String input. Here is the console output:

```
Enter the item
box
Enter the price
5.2
{box=5.2}
Enter the item
Enter the price
item
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input.nextLine() takes the Scanner to the next line of input, but input.nextDouble() does not. Therefore, you'll need to either advance the Scanner to the next line:

```
            price = input.nextDouble();
            input.nextLine();
```

Or, you can use nextLine() directly instead and parse that into a Double:

```
            price = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());
```

See this question for further details: [Java: .nextLine() and .nextDouble() differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551985/java-nextline-and-nextdouble-differences)

Answer (score 0):

Add input.nextLine() as below:

```
String item;
        double price;

        while(running == true){

            System.out.println("Enter the item");

            item = input.nextLine();

            input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the price");

            price = input.nextDouble();

            input.nextLine();

            inv.put(item, price);

           System.out.println(inv);

        }
```